# typescript, bug with Partial<T>?

Tags: typescript

The following code raise an error. But the `if` ensures that `e` is not undefined.
Is this a bug from typescript or a normal behaviour ? Also, what is the correct way to do this ?

```js
function Foo<T>(data: T, partialData: Partial<T>, key: keyof T) {
    const e = partialData[key];
    if (e)
        data[key] = e;
}
```

```
Type 'T[keyof T] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `as T[keyof T]` like this to fix the issue:

```
function Foo<T>(data: T, partialData: Partial<T>, key: keyof T) {
    const e = partialData[key];
    if (e)
        data[key] = e as T[keyof T];
}
```

here you check it in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAMTnAPAFQHwAoAmAhlIQFyKYA0iADoQE6yEA2AIsWYgAoNPNbZqAawCmAT3KixcYBQCUiAN4AoRGsQQEAZyiIRiALy1eMFuxIBtKQF0A3KvUxZuEXIfr1RSzcN7EhLQorcRkKO2UAXyA)